# Kafka Streams - accessing data from the metrics registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having a difficult time finding documentation on how to access the data within the Kafka Streams metric registry, and I think I may be trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. I was hoping to get some advice on the following:

### Goal

Collect metrics being recorded in the [Kafka Streams metrics registry](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.java#L102) and send these values to an arbitrary end point

### Workflow

This is what I *think* needs to be done, and I've complete all of the steps except the last (having trouble with that one because the metrics registry is private). But I may be going about this the wrong way:

- Define a class that implements the `MetricReporter` interface. Build a list of the metrics that Kafka creates in the `metricChange` method (e.g. whenever this method is called, update a hashmap with the currently registered metrics).
- Specify this class in the `metric.reporters` configuration property
- Set up a process that polls the Kafka Streams metric registry for the current data, and ship the values to an arbitrary end point

Anyways, the last step doesn't appear to be possible in Kafka **0.10.0.1** since the metrics registry isn't exposed. Could some please let me know this if is the correct workflow (sounds like it's not..), or if I am misunderstanding the process for extracting the Kafka Streams metrics?

Comment: Have you already read http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html and http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#monitoring? Excerpt: "You can monitor individual components of Kafka using Apache Kafka’s internal metrics. Kafka uses Yammer Metrics for metrics reporting in both the server and the client. This can be configured to report stats using pluggable stats reporters to hook up to your monitoring system."  See also https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-kafka-performance-metrics/, for example, which explains how to tap into Kafka's metrics via JMX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the metrics registry is not exposed, you can still get the value of a given `KafkaMetric` by its `KafkaMetric.value()` / `KafkaMetric.value(timestamp)` methods. For example, as you observed in the JMXRporter, it keeps the list of KafkaMetrics from the instantiated `init()` and `metricChange/metricRemoval` methods, and then in its `MBean` implementation, when `getAttribute` is called, it will call its corresponding `KafkaMetrics.value()` function. So for your customized reporter, you can apply similar patterns, for example, periodically poll all kept `KafkaMetrics.value()` and then pipe the results to your end point.

Answer (score 0):

The MetricReporter interface in org.apache.kafka.common.metrics already enables you to manage all Kafka stream metrics in the reporter. So kafka internal registry is not needed.